# PHP, mysqli query excuted but did not update data in database

Tags: php, mysqli

When i click on the button it shows that my query is executed. But when I checked my database, there is no change/update. I have tried many ways on how to solve it, and read a lot of related questions here and tried the answers but nothing is working for me.

Here is my code:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
include_once('config_db.php');

function documentReceived($id){
    $updateRece = "UPDATE shipping SET `document_received`='1' WHERE id='".$id."'";
    if($GLOBALS['conn']->query($updateRece) == TRUE){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo $updateRece;
    }
}
function saveRating($rat, $id){
    $rating = "UPDATE shipping SET `rating`='".$rat."', `car_received`='1' WHERE id='".$id."'";
    if($GLOBALS['conn']->query($rating) == TRUE){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo $up;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'documentReceived'){
    documentReceived($_POST['id']);
}else if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'saveRating'){
    saveRating($_POST['rating'], $_POST['id']);
}
```

Comment: dont put smart quotes around column names

Comment: i tried with removing smart quotes around column names but not working

Comment: it is working well on my local machine but giving problem on live server

Comment: Can do once PHP debug: " ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); " Then check what exact error is showing

Comment: i try to ini_set("display_errors", 1); and error_reporting(E_ALL). and still it showing success message

Comment: Whatever your `query` method does, are you sure it returns `TRUE` if everything is alright? Is there any kind of error handling to see whether MySQL returned an error?

Comment: Issue fixed thank you guyes

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this

```
function documentReceived($id) {
    $updateRece = "UPDATE shipping SET `document_received`='1' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
    if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $updateRece)) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo $updateRece;
    }
}

function saveRating($rat, $id) {
    $rating = "UPDATE shipping SET `rating`='" . $rat . "', `car_received`='1' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
    if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $rating)) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo $up;
    }
}
```

in above code i have changed

```
if($GLOBALS['conn']->query($updateRece) == TRUE){
```

to

```
if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $updateRece)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Sunny Kalariya
but still same issue. it is giving success but did not effect db